# rails 3 unit test not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

The following code exists in `test/unit/this_stupid_test.rb`

```
require 'test/unit'

class ThisStupidTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def better_be_true
    assert true
  end
end
```

When I run `rake test:units` it says `finished with 0 tests and 0 assertions`.

It says the same thing when I run `ruby test/unit/this_stupid_test.rb`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your method definition to `def test_better_be_true`.

Comment: That got it, lol. I didn't realize there was a naming convention there, thanks for the info. I'll accept your answer here in a little bit once it lets me.